# R-plotting a PDF of a truncated normal

Tags: r, plot, distribution, truncated

Any idea how can I plot this truncated normal PDF in R. The mean is 0 with variance 1 so the PDF is:
`exp((-x^2)/2)) * I{x>=2}` where `I` is an indicator function.  Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing simpler. Try:

```
x <- seq(-5, 5, by=0.01)
plot(x[x >= 2], exp((-x^2)/2)[x >= 2])
```